# (Too) Many network adapters, why?

Tags: windows-8, network-adapter

As shown in the image, I have `VMware` and `Juniper Network` installed, but there are still too many `TAP-Windows Adapter` or `TAP-Win32 Adapter`.

[image: much connection]

What are these connections? How can I remove these?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following and they will disappear.

1. Press Win+R -> Type in `msinfo32` and press Enter.
2. Now you will see the following console window.

   [image]
   <sup>**MSinfo32 console**</sup>
3. In the left pane navigate to *Components* -> *Network* -> *Adapter*. Here you can see all the Network Adapters listed. Find the TAP adapters and see the Driver location as shown in the below image.

   [image]
   <sup>**Location of TAP adapter driver**</sup>

   I have given a sample image as I have already deleted the TAP adapters. Don't delete the Microsoft Adapters. Find the TAP adapters location in listed adapters and go to the location, for example: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\TAP.sys` and delete them.
4. After this just go to Device Management and uninstall the TAP adapters under Network Adapters.

   Note: While uninstalling tick the option "Delete the Driver" if asked for a prompt.

That's it, you're done.

Comment: Why wouldn't somebody just skip the first 2 steps and just uninstall the TAP adapters.  Why go to the system folder and delete the driver manually?